# Append attribute value in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, youtube, tinymce

Youtube's new embed code is like this:

```
  <iframe
    width="560"
    height="345"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rFuUFeQIdpk"
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

TinyMCE pastes this fine but the problem is that I need to add **"?wmode=opaque"** to the src attribute for obvious CSS/DOM reasons.  I really want to find a in-TinyMCE solution if possible (of course, if none is avail I can obviously whip up some jQuery...but that's a LAST resort).

So far I have:
valid_elements:'iframe[width|height|src|allowfullscreen]'

And I noticed that the doc on tinyMCE says they accept wild cards for matching - but I can't seem to make them work.

For example, something like this:
valid_elements:'iframe[width|height|src=*+\?wmode\=opaque|allowfullscreen]'

(but of course, that doesn't work)

thoughts?  ideas?

Comment: So Jason, do you want *?wmode=opaque* to add to the SRC attribute when you paste into TinyMCE or when do you want to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add `&amp;wmode=Opaque` to the src?
If this does not work try `&amp;wmode=transparent`.

If you don't know how to modify the src attribute after paste you may use the paste plugin and add some code to the [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste) setting.
This should do it

```
o.content.replace(/src=\"(.*?)"/g, "$1&amp;wmode=Opaque");
```